# Putting the pieces together

Tags: riddle, word

My prefix prints

My infix expresses frustration

My suffix is often exclaimed

My whole goes one step at a time

Hint:

> A word in the title is very helpful!

> It is not worth a great deal

> You could say that its friends have a greater degree of freedom than it does.

Big and last hint

> It can also move two steps under special circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is:

> **PAWN**

*My prefix prints*

> An animal's **PAW** leaves a print on the ground.

*My infix expresses frustration*

> **AW** can be an exclamation of disappointment.

*My suffix is often exclaimed*

> **WN** is an abbreviation for "*What now?!*", something that might be exclaimed aloud.
>
>  *The OP states in comments that their intention here was merely **N**, as a reference to "**n!**", the mathematical shorthand for a general [**factorial**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial). 'Exclaimed' here is a reference to the use of an exclamation mark...*

*My whole goes one step at a time*

> In general, a **PAWN** moves just one space at a time across the chessboard (except of course for it's opening move, which may be 2 steps - hinted by the 4th clue). The 2nd and 3rd clue are references to the pawn being considered the least powerful piece on the board, considering that all other pieces can move in many more directions or over greater distances.

As for the title:

> The '*pieces*' mentioned are **chess pieces**!

Comment: Finally...well done!!

Comment: But the suffix is referring to n factorial n!.

Comment: @Deepthinker101 Ah, okay - I'll edit that in...

Comment: Also the title has a double meaning relevant to this puzzle as it refers to putting the puzzle pieces together and laying out the chess pieces on the board.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are

> pressure

My prefix prints

> press

My infix expresses frustration

> ss - hissing noise

My suffix is often exclaimed

> sure!

My whole goes one step at a time

> stress/pressure

Comment: Nice try but it is not the answer. HINT: The title is a clue too